# When downloading a javascript file from the internet, where does it go?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, uiwebview

I'm using a code like this:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/download.js"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
// Save this following url to load the file
return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: __URL_YOU_SAVED_AVOBE__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

Every time the app is opened, this code downloads a js file and loads it on to a uiwebview. What happens to the javascript file that is downloaded and loaded onto the uiwebview? Is it saved in the app? Is it saved on the iPhone? Every time the app is opened and the file is downloaded, is it taking up GB and memory on the iPhone? But seriously, where does the file go? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file save on disk with the destination when you created the NSURLSessionDownloadTask. 
You can delete the file with NSFileManager for sure, check it's api.
If you want a execute only js file, use NSString load from the source url so the "JS String" will be on RAM only every time you call this action.Then you can execute it on your webview as js.
Satisfy?

Comment: Would you have an example of how to "execute only js file, use NSString load from the source url so the "JS String" will be on RAM only every time you call this action.Then you can execute it on your webview as js."?

Comment: There is a method call "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" in UIWebView, very straight forward.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see last line of your codes.  What I meant is you can instantiate the NSString by using the initWithContentsOfURL(_:_:_:), rather than download it on disk if it's your concern. Need to be noticed, this method will block the current queue so you would have a better experience to do it on some background queue and update back in the main queue.